# App doesn't appear in Applications or Downloads folder after OTA Download

Tags: deployment, blackberry, mobile, blackberry-jde

I have a Blackberry app on my web-server. When a user downloads via the BlackBerry Browser the JAD file is installed automatically, but does not appear in the Downloads folder or in the installed Applications folder. Did I do something wrong with my deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to restart the device (battery pull) before the icon will appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your application is installed by going to `Options->Advanced Options->Applications` and seeing if your app is listed there. This will tell you if your app is installed on handset.